# How to setup up one-click installer on IIS 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I want to setup my iis to use the one-click installer web deploy method. I however don't how to setup this up as I can't find any tutorials really on it.

The only tutorial I found was this:

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/05/web-1-click-publish-with-vs-2010.html

and it says they would cover the part of installing it on iis 7 in another tutorial but I don't see that tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is install Web Deploy in the Server (http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) and that will give you a couple of tasks inside IIS Manager that you can right-click at the Site and choose Deploy->Import Package, and select the package generated in VS 2010. YOu can also just use the command line to do that without the need to specify parameters:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618002431/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/06/25/a-practical-example-of-using-web-application-deployment-package-with-iis7.aspx)

If you want to be able to publish remotely you need to configure the Management Service as well:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120212172726/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/06/05/basic-microsoft-web-deployment-tool-setup-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx)